# Xcode ibeacon advice

Tags: ios, ibeacon

My app layout:

1. Menu - Sub-Menu 1, Sub-Menu
2. Sub-Menu 1- Item1, Item 2
3. Sub-Menu 2- Item1, Item 2

When an app detects a beacon, it will lead the user to either Menu or Sub-Menu or Item in Sub-Menus. Meaning I can jump to any Sub-Menu or Item.

Single region, same UUID, differentiate only my major and minor ID.

Where should I put startRangingBeaconsInRegion? Should it be on every page?

Comment: Use AppDelegate or Create Separate Class/Manager that handle beacon related code and use delegate or Notification to inform ViewController for Beacon Major or Minor etc.

Comment: Nope, it should be at one place, you should create a separate class which can handle all entry/exit calls for your beacons. This will make future enhancements easy and a way clear implementation.